# GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter custom and default

Tags: android, google-maps, markers

I have an app with google maps containing a few markers with personalized `InfoWindowAdapter` [1].
This works well but now I want to add a few more markers and I do not pretend to use the same personalized infoWindow. The default is OK for that. The problem is when I click in one of the last added markers i get the error: `java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception length=1 index=1`. I think this happens because these new markers are using the custom `infoAdapter` of the first markers, so my question is: how i can set the last markers with the default `infoAdapter`?

I have read that: 'To replace the default info window, override `getInfoWindow(Marker)` with your custom rendering and return null for `getInfoContents(Marker)`. To replace only the info window contents inside the default info window frame (the callout bubble), return `null` in `getInfoWindow(Marker)` and override `getInfoContents(Marker)` instead' and try something like [2] but without success.

Anybody knows how to fix that?

[1]

```
private class poisInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            String SnippetContent = marker.getSnippet();
            String[] parts = SnippetContent.split("//");

            // Get Layout of POI's popup's and assign JSON values to text views.
            View InfoPopupLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infopopup,null);

            TextView t = ((TextView) InfoPopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.title));
            t.setText(marker.getTitle());

            TextView p = (TextView) InfoPopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.parking);
            p.setText(getString(R.string.parking_pwd) + convertInfoPoisValues(parts[2]));

            return InfoPopupLayout;
    }
}
```

[2]

```
private class poisInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.getTitle() == "Obstáculo") {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            String SnippetContent = marker.getSnippet();
            String[] parts = SnippetContent.split("//");

            // Get Layout of POI's popup's and assign JSON values to text views.
            View InfoPopupLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infopopup,null);

            TextView t = ((TextView) InfoPopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.title));
            t.setText(marker.getTitle());

            TextView p = (TextView) InfoPopupLayout.findViewById(R.id.parking);
            p.setText(getString(R.string.parking_pwd) + convertInfoPoisValues(parts[2]));

            return InfoPopupLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, i just have to use 'equals' in  '(marker.getTitle() == "Obstáculo")'.